# Find Function in a Userform based on multiple criteria

Tags: vba, excel, search, userform

I created a userform which has several `textboxes` and I use the `foundcell` to return the values of a line based on a reference number.

What I am wanting to do however is search a reference which is based in the `searchrange` below which is in  and if `.Range("AK")` is blank to return. Else a msgbox to say that the criteria is not valid.

Please see me attempted code

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim searchRange As Range
Dim foundCell As Range
Dim mysearch As String

mysearch = Ref.Value

With Sheets("X")
    Set searchRange = Sheets("X").Range("AB2", .Range("AB" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
End With

Set foundCell = searchRange.Find(what:=mysearch, Lookat:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

        If Not foundCell And foundCell.Offset(0, 9) Is Nothing Then

            Me.C.Value = foundCell.Offset(0, -12).Value
            Me.DD.Value = foundCell.Offset(0, -10).Value
            Me.RD.Value = foundCell.Offset(0, -16).Value
            Me.BN.Value = foundCell.Offset(0, -9).Value
            Me.FN.Value = foundCell.Offset(0, -8).Value
            Me.SHARP.Value = foundCell.Offset(0, -1).Value
            Me.PGP.Value = foundCell.Offset(0, -7).Value
            Me.ISS.Value = foundCell.Offset(0, -6).Value
            Me.DE.Value = foundCell.Offset(0, -2).Value
            Me.UN.Value = foundCell.Offset(0, -5).Value
            Me.W.Value = foundCell.Offset(0, -4).Value
            Me.IN.Value = foundCell.Offset(0, -3).Value
            Me.CVAL.Value = foundCell.Offset(0, -20).Value
            Me.ADD.Value = foundCell.Offset(0, -11).Value
            Me.RESPONSE.Value = foundCell.Offset(0, 1).Value
            Me.NRESPONSE.Value = foundCell.Offset(0, 2).Value
            Me.MAREC.Value = foundCell.Offset(0, 4).Value
            Me.MORET.Value = foundCell.Offset(0, 5).Value
            Me.CNREC.Value = foundCell.Offset(0, 8).Value
            Me.CNREF.Value = foundCell.Offset(0, 6).Value
            Me.NVALUE.Value = foundCell.Offset(0, 7).Value
            Me.CBY.Value = foundCell.Offset(0, 10).Value
            Me.CDAT.Value = foundCell.Offset(0, 11).Value

        Else

            MsgBox "The Reference you have entered does not qualify and cannot be located. Please try another reference!"
End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to null-check `foundCell` on its own conditional, VBA's `And` logical operator doesn't short-circuit like VB.NET's `AndAlso` and C#'s `&&` operator.

```
If Not foundCell Is Nothing Then
```

Also `foundCell.Offset(0,9)` could contain an error value, which will make any comparison operation throw a "Type Mismatch" run-time error. Use `IsError` to verify its error state *before* you assume it contains anything other than an error:

```
    If Not IsError(foundCell.Offset(0, 9).Value) Then
```

Lastly, if your intent is to verify whether `foundCell.Offset(0, 9)` isn't empty, you can check in several ways, but `Is Nothing` isn't one of them:

- `IsBlank(foundCell.Offset(0, 9).Value)` will return `True` if the cell contains nothing - no value, no formula.
- `foundCell.Offset(0, 9).Value <> vbNullString` will return `True` if the cell's value is an empty string, or if its formula evaluates to an empty string.
- `foundCell.Offset(0, 9).Value <> ""` will do the same as `<> vbNullString`.

Thus:

```
If Not foundCell Is Nothing Then
    If Not IsBlank(foundCell.Offset(0, 9).Value) Then
```

Or:

```
If Not foundCell Is Nothing Then
    If Not IsError(foundCell.Offset(0, 9).Value) Then
        If foundCell.Offset(0, 9).Value <> vbNullString Then
```

Answer (score -2):

If Not foundCell Is Nothing And foundCell.Offset(0, 9) <> """" Then

Comment: This will raise run-time error 91 whenever `foundCell Is Nothing`. Conditional expressions do NOT short-circuit in VBA, they're fully evaluated regardless of the first part evaluating to `False`. Also `<> """"` means you're verifying that the cell doesn't *literally* contain two double-quotes, which at a glance looks like it will evaluate to `True` whenever `foundCell` isn't `Nothing`.